# Broken icon of Skype in the Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, skype, taskbar, icons

Usually, I have Skype pinned to the taskbar on Windows 7 and its icon prints normally. For a few days, this icon has seemed broken/not found :

[image: broken icon in taskbar]

If I un-pin the program from the taskbar, the icon shows as usual :

[image]

But if I re-pin it (or even simply right-click on it), the icon is broken again.

The program itself doesn't bug for the moment, but I wonder why this happens, and how I could fix this.

**EDIT** : My question has been marked as a possible duplicate (see comments), but the fixes provided to the other thread don't work for me, which is why I need other methods of fixing this.

**UPDATE** : After magicandre's and user1167442's answers, the icon now looks like this :

[image: New icon]

**UPDATE 2** : When I right-click on the pinned Skype "icon", then right-click again on the program's name to see its properties (see screenshot) ; when I click on "Change icon", a dialog box says

> File not found : %SystemRoot%\Installer{6A0549A9-...-B19}\SkypeIcon.exe.

[image: Change Icon]

I also noticed the link's target is joined with the `/secondary` argument, which is still there even when I erase it and apply.

Comment: @DavidPostill I had to accept his answer because my fix is largely based on it. But his answer didn't work as is for me. See my comment on his post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Unpin the app
2. Go to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`
3. Find (if exists) an icon for Skype and delete.
4. Press `Win+R`
5. In input box type `cmd /c taskkill /f /im explorer.exe && explorer.exe`
6. Open Skype's folder (located in `%PROGRAMFILES%` or `PROGRAMFILES(x86)`)
7. Right click `Skype.exe` (make sure not `Skype.lnk` - *although `lnk` file would probably work too, but using the exe may circumvent something that is not worth explaining* ) and select  `pin to taskbar`

Should be good

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work either (in the end, I have the same "exe icon" than in my Update). (And I'd enjoy to know why it is better to pin Skype.exe than Skype.lnk !)

Comment: I fixed this by following your indications, but at the step 7, before selecting `pin to the taskbar`, I linked the `Skype.exe` to the `...\User Pinned\TaskBar` folder, then I pinned the original `Skype.exe` and it appeared with the right icon on the taskbar. Then I deleted my first manual link in the `TaskBar` folder and renamed "Skype (2)" to "Skype". No idead why this worked though...

Comment: Why exe instead of lnk is because exe has original ico file embedded inside.  Link uses icon by reference which is easier to break if path changes or something.  In my experience, this happens more than you think it would

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a broken Icon cache, so try to [rebuild the icon cache](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html) by running those commands:

```
ie4uinit.exe -ClearIconCache
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
DEL "%localappdata%\IconCache.db" /A
shutdown /r /f /t 00
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work (see the update on OP). It would have been nice to simply tell me to reboot my system after the first 3 commands instead of making me copy/paste a shutdown with a 0 second delay... A luck I know what the `shutdown` command is and I could save my work before rebooting...

Comment: it looks like the icon file in C:\Windows\Installer gets deleted. Which Av suite do you use?.